# Extracting a parameter from a function passed as parameter

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++98

I have a following function:

```
void Class1::MainThreadFunction(const __int64 param) {
    if(GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID) {
        RunInMainThread(MainThreadFunction, param);
        return;
    }
    //...
}

void Class2::RunInMainThread(void(__closure* FuncToCall)(const __int64 ParToExtract),
                             const __int64 fP1) {
    struct {
        __int64 P1;
        void(__closure* F)(const __int64);

        void __fastcall FTC() { F(P1); }
    } Args = {fP1, FuncToCall};

    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &Args.FTC);
}
```

So what I am attempting to do is to extract the first parameter in `FuncToCall` which is named `ParToExtract` above to be used for initializing the `Args` structure. In other words the `P1` in the struct should receive the `const __int64` from the passed function which is named as `ParToExtract`.

The above works but I currently as a workaround pass the parameter as `fP1` which I use to initialize `P1` but there surely must be a better way to do this.

Additional bonus would be to have the variable number of function parameters in `RunInMainThread` (but I have for the moment to avoid C++11 `<functional>`).

Please no lambda-based (or C++11 features) - this is another thing I cannot yet use for the moment.

Comment: A parameter is an *input* to a function. You cannot "extract" it from the function; you have to pass a value *to* the function.

Comment: @ted-lyngmo Not sure you you reformated my Whitesmiths style to K&R style. This is a personal preference and should not be altered (and one style is in no way superior to the other).

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but not indenting function bodies is just ... ew.

Comment: @Coder12345 Sorry, I've never seen style like that survive a code review ever and mistook it for a mistake. Feel free to edit it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you already have is the correct (and only) way to approach this situation in C++Builder's "classic" (pre-C++11) compilers.

In order to support a variable number of parameters, you will have to use multiple overloads, there is no other option (without delving into low-level inline assembly to setup call stacks manually, but even then it may not work correctly across thread boundaries), eg:

```cpp
void Class1::MainThreadFunction()
{
    if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
        RunInMainThread(MainThreadFunction);
        return;
    }
    //...
}

void Class1::MainThreadFunction(const __int64 param)
{
    if(GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
        RunInMainThread(MainThreadFunction, param);
        return;
    }
    //...
}

// and so on as needed ...
```

```cpp
template<typename FuncType>
void Class2::RunInMainThread(FuncType FuncToCall)
{
    struct {
        FuncType F;
        void __fastcall FTC() { F(); }
    } Args = {FuncToCall};

    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &Args.FTC);
}

template<typename FuncType, typename ParamType>
void Class2::RunInMainThread(FuncType FuncToCall, const ParamType param)
{
    struct {
        const ParamType &P;
        FuncType F;
        void __fastcall FTC() { F(P); }
    } Args = {param, FuncToCall};

    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &Args.FTC);
}

template<typename FuncType, typename ParamType1, typename ParamType2>
void Class2::RunInMainThread(FuncType FuncToCall, const ParamType1 param1, const ParamType2 param2)
{
    struct {
        const ParamType1 &P1;
        const ParamType2 &P2;
        FuncType F;
        void __fastcall FTC() { F(P1, P2); }
    } Args = {param1, param2, FuncToCall};

    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &Args.FTC);
}

// and so on as needed...
```

If you look through various RTL header files, such as `sysvari.h` and `utilcls.h`, using overloads is how Borland itself approaches the issue of variable number of parameters in several of its own APIs, sometimes upwards of 30+ parameters, which is more than enough to handle most user code.

Answer (score 3):

The signature for the method called by `TThread::Synchronize()` must match the `TThreadMethod` type:

```
void __fastcall (__closure *TThreadMethod)(void);
```

So you can't pass parameters through it directly. Instead of going through a proxy function, use a lambda:

```
void MainThreadFunction(int64_t param) {
    if(GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
        TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, [&param]{ MainThreadFunction(param); } );
    //...
}
```

In order to have a variable number of parameters, you could make it a function template:

```
template< class... Args >
void MainThreadFunction(Args&&... args) {
    if(GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
        TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, [&args...] {
                MainThreadFunction(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
            }
        );
    //...
}
```

When using a classic (pre C++11) compiler, you'd usually use a class private variable to carry the information.

Comment: Note the lambda approach only works in the Clang-based compilers. In the classic compilers, the struct wrapper is the correct solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I've mentioned in my original question I wasn't looking for a lambda solution. I have to use for a while a classic compiler before I switch to a newer one which supports lambdas.

Comment: @Coder12345 I see no mentioning of the _no lambda_ requirement. Lambdas aren't a part of `<functional>`. Lambdas are an integral part of the language since C++11. Good point Remy, added note about that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, OK, I didn't explicitly mentioned it. But `<functional>` is a part of C++11 standard. I've updated the question. Thank you for the additional reply as well.

Comment: Yes it is, and so are lambas. You didn't say "no C++11 features", you specificallly mentioned one header, and this answer does not require that header.